# How to return a set of urls with more accuracy that returns relevant result, using web scraping?

Tags: database, web-scraping

I want to extract a bunch of urls from a db *(the db contains a large set of urls)*, when a user searches for a particular keyword, for example "seattle dentist". I understand that the basic approach is to look for the page title, meta description, keywords and body text.

How can I do this with more accuracy that returns relevant result?

For example, I have two websites in question:

1. `seattledentist.com` (which is a dentist website and has the title
   "seattle dentist")
2. `abcxyz.com/dentist-seattle`  (a wordpress blog
   page that has the word "seattle dentist" in its title)

For me, the first website is relevant and I want to show this site to a user when he searches for "seattle dentist".
The second website is just a blog post that describes the dentistry profession in seattle and is not relevant for the user.

So my question is, what would be a better strategy(algorithm) for filtering out this type of non-relevant urls from a whole bunch of urls?

Comment: How would you deal with a site for a Seattle dentist that is just their business name, which may not contain either word? Also, a question that can be summarised as 'How to revolutionise search engines?' is too broad for SO.

Comment: In that case, my approach would be to take both title and page content into consideration. But my primary concern is how can I filter out irrelevant results. (to be specific, just the example I have asked)

Comment: Your question is too broad for stack overflow. You may get better luck on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://cs.stackexchange.com/